# Вращение в пределах сферического сегмента

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

Есть абстрактный корабль, который может двигаться и вращаться в трех измерениях. Где-то к этому кораблю приделена турель. Турель может вращаться как угодно, но нужно ограниченное вращение в пределах определенного угла (сегмента сферы). Имеется цель, на которую нужно наводиться и отсюда вращение, которое нужно установить, чтобы быть полностью наведенным на цель (кватернион). Нужно как-то переделать имеющееся вращение во вращение, которое бы позволяло следовать за целью как можно ближе к допустимой границе, не пересекая ее ("скольжение" по границе этого сегмента сферы).

---

Пикча для представления (определенно сфера):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Допустимый угол в 30 градусов.
2. Допустимый угол в 15-30 градусов.

Comment: Возможно, придется кватернион переводить в углы Эйлера, ограничивать там и переводить обратно

Comment: такой вопрос вы `localRotation` использовали или `rotation`?

Answer (score 0):

В библиотеках Unity есть структура Matf, а в ней функция Clamp, ограничивающая значения. Допустим вам нужно ограничить вокруг оси Y (смотреть по сторонам) по 40 градусов в каждую сторону:

```
[SerializeField] private float _sensivity = 3f;
[SerializeField] private float _minAngle = -40f;
[SerializeField] private float _maxAngle = 40f;

private float _rotationX = 0f;

void Update()
{
    _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensivity;
    _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, _minAngle, _maxAngle);
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, _rotationX, 0);
}
```